# ASP.NET MVC Routing, TransferRequestHandler dont work in ClassicMode with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have a web site in my local IIS.
The Application Pool for this site it is in Clasic Mode.

I am mapping a path of a file to a route on MVC.

I have the route register like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "XMLPath",
        url: "sitemapindex.xml",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Html", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

In my controller I have this method

```
public FileResult Html()
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("<sitemapindex xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("<sitemap>");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("<loc>http://[site]/sitemaps/sitemap_01.xml</loc>");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("<lastmod>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt") + "</lastmod>");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("</sitemap>");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("<sitemap>");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("<loc>http://[site]/sitemaps/sitemap_02.xml</loc>");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("<lastmod>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt") + "</lastmod>");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("</sitemap>");
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("</sitemapindex>");

    var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString()));

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=sitemapindex.xml");

    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "text/xml");
}
```

And in my web.cong I add this

```
<handlers>
    <add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
<runtime>
```

All this is similar to 
http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works

The only differences is that using preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"  not preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0".

If I run the project in Visual Studio 2013 work perfect, but when I run it in the IIS doesn't works. If I change the AppPool of my IIS to integrate mode works.
But I need to have the AppPool in Classic Mode.

When I run the Route (url) [site]/sitemapindex.xml in classic mode I get this error:

HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "HtmlFileHandler" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

This a [Example Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6qsowt919ivex1/XmlTest.rar?dl=0) that I am using.
How I can used System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler in classicMode in a IIS Site?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at source code of TransferRequestHandler, its clear that it requires application to be run in integrated mode. If its able to typecast WorkerRequest as IIS7WorkerRequest then it means its running in integrated mode.

```
internal class TransferRequestHandler : IHttpHandler {        
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        IIS7WorkerRequest wr = context.WorkerRequest as IIS7WorkerRequest;
        if (wr == null) {
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.GetString(SR.Requires_Iis_Integrated_Mode));
        }            
        wr.ScheduleExecuteUrl(null,
                              null,
                              null,
                              true,
                              context.Request.EntityBody,
                              null,
                              preserveUser: false);            
        context.ApplicationInstance.EnsureReleaseState();
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pablo you can still map a Handler used in Classic Mode on IIs7 by just changing your web.config file to use the httpHandler section rather than the handler section. Here are the instructions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx

The reason you have to do this is because Classic IIS pipeline mode in older IIs used a separate ISAPI extension, which stood between IIs and the .NET Runtime / worker process. In the newer IIs7 Integrated mode the ISAPI Extension is gone and manages handlers inside the .NET worker process itself. Because you are mixing the older classic ISAPI extension pipeline piece with the newer IIs7 server setup you have to manage that handler setup via the older web.config settings.